Unreal Engine 5: in Preferences, 'general - Keyboard shortcuts' why are there two fields for every command?
There are two fields for every command as shown below:

Is this just a convenient means of  assigning two different shortcuts to a command? Or is this something to do with key chords?
The documentation does not touch on this at all, I would like to know conclusively.

Key chords has a musical meaning, but I've never heard of it used as a UI term; did you mean key combinations (for example ctrl + C for copy)?

@Pikalek No, Ctrrl+C would be one "shortcut key". "Chords" is a concept used in source editors like vim, VScode, SublimeText, etc etc. In the VScode documentation "Keyboard rules" section "chords" are defined as "two separate keypress actions", like ctrl+a followed by ctrl+f. I am thinking Unreal is not referring to this concept though. It seems in Unreal's case, its just a convenient design that allows one to assign two different shortcut keys to the same command, why? beats me.

I guess OP asked the same question on unrealengine.com, where someone responded:

Customizing Keyboard Shortcuts
It says:

Each command can have up to two keyboard shortcuts associated with it
So it looks like it is just two slots. (I have seen many programs with 1 slot per command, or many slots per command, but never exactly two.)


(I don't deserve credit but the comment section is too short)
